# Find all the textboxes that has id with common name jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find all the text boxes within each row of column  and retrieve attributes values in a stringbuilder.

```
<table width="100%" class="normal" id="tblResults" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
    <TBODY>
    <TR class=header>
    <TH class=sortLPad title="Sort by URN" onclick="reSort('0')" align=left>URN </TH>

    <TH class=sortLPad title="Sort by ShowRoom" onclick="reSort('5')" align=left>Show Room</TH></TR>

    <P></P>

    <TR EventId="504">
    <TD id=URN noWrap>23KV9878788</TD> 

    <TD id="ShowRoom" class=lPad><INPUT onfocusin=clearField(this); id="ShowRoom0" onfocusout=resetField(this); onkeypress=validate(this) maxLength=1 value=1 size=1 version="2000120420142859" elementname="ShowRoom" engineid="504" carid="244"></TD>

    </TR>

    <TR EventId="403">
    <TD id=URN noWrap>889878744</TD> 

    <TD id="ShowRoom" class=lPad><INPUT onfocusin=clearField(this); id="ShowRoom2" onfocusout=resetField(this); onkeypress=validate(this) maxLength=1 value=1 size=1 version="2000120420142859" elementname="ShowRoom" engineid="882" carid="442"></TD>

    </TR>

    </TBODY>
</Table>

<input type="button" id="continue" value="continue">
```

Here is the Jquery i tried

```
    $("#continue").click(function(){
       alert("Clicked");

     $("#tblResults TBODY TR").each(function(i, row){
          alert("each tr" + i + row);

            var elementValue = $(this).child('td').find('input[id*="ShowRoom"]');

        alert($(elementValue).attr("carid"));

       });
  });
});
```

first issue it isn't looping thru each row? second never reaches `alert($(elemnetValue).attr("carid"));`

Comment: Ids be unique in HTML. ShowRoom ids repeated in your html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dLzcr0yL/1/

Comment: @JqueryKing: I tried changing the TD id's to be unique didn't make any difference. I am after the input type=text which has unique id.

Comment: You should take a look at an HTML style guide. You are mixing up upper case and lower case letters. Just stick to one and preferably lowercase. like `<td></td>` instead of `<TD></TD>` and `<table></table>` instead of `<table></Table>´... ([style guide](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp)). You also shouldn't edit your question with the answer, because now you have a question with perfectly fine working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has no `.child()` method so that line of your code is likely causing an error and stopping execution of your code (you should be looking in the debug log to see errors like this).

You can change this:

```
var elemnetValue = $(this).child('td').find('input[id*="ShowRoom"]');
```

to this:

```
var elemnetValue = $(this).find('input[id*="ShowRoom"]');
```

---

But, you can simplify even further by changing this:

```
   $("#tblResults TBODY TR").each(function(i, row){
        var elemnetValue = $(this).find('input[id*="ShowRoom"]');
        if (elemnetValue.length) {
            console.log(elemnetValue.attr("carid"));
        }
   });
```

to this:

```
   $('#tblResults input[id*="ShowRoom"]').each(function(i, item){
       console.log($(this).attr("carid"));
   });
```

---

P.S. Most people spell the word it looks like you're trying to use as `element`, not `elemnet`.

Comment: I am using w3schools as the actual application is quite a heavy one and takes longer to build. Thanks that helped how do i avoid looping thru headers row. If i want to loop thru each row that has attribute EventID? is this possible $("#tblResults TBODY TR").attr("Eventid").each(function(i, row){

Comment: $('#tblResults tr[Eventid]').each(function(){})

Comment: @Gauls - you don't need to iterate by row at all.  You can just find all the matching `input[id*="ShowRoom"]` objects in the table.  See my latest edit for a shortened version that just lets the CSS selector do all the work for you.  There are no matching `input` tags in the header rows so you don't need to write code to skip them.

Comment: @jfriend00: I am using the second option that also helps to avoid the headers issue. the first code couldn't  find the input it pops up as undefined.var elementValue = $(this).find('input[id*="ShowRoom"]');

Comment: Yeah, in the first code you have to check if it actually found any `input` elements in that row by checking `if (elemnetValue.length)` first.  But, the second code suggestion is definitely simpler and better anyway.

Comment: I had one more query what is the best way to concatenate eg: "carid1|engineid1,carid2,engineid2" $('#tblResults input[id*="ShowRoom"]').each(function(i, item){

        strValue = $(this).attr("carid") + '|' + $(this).attr("engineid");
  

       alert(strValue);
   }).get().join(","); -> this is not working?

Comment: @Gauls - sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Since your original question has been answered and multi-line code is really not readable in comments, perhaps you should ask a new question for this new issue where you can properly describe the desired output and show the code you've tried.

Comment: @jfriend00: The question is related to this example thought it is more opt to ask here "and retrieve attributes values in a stringbuilder". I can update the jquery for concatenate question if you like?

Comment: @Gauls - StackOverflow just isn't set up well for a continuing stream of questions after the first one has been fully answered.  I'm often willing to field additional follow-on questions in comments (just to help out) until it gets to the point of we need to be sharing code and larger amounts of info than easily and clearly fit in comments.  I think you've passed that threshold here.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery function you are looking for is `.children()` not `.child()`.